# Socket Client connection

Tags: sockets, networking, client

I am trying to learn how to use sockets in java
I have typed in the example from [Tutorials point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm) but I can't get it working (Socket Client Example).
The only changes I made was that instead of taking the port & host name from `args` passed in, I am hard-coding the port and getting the local host. The code I have is as follows

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetClient
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      InetAddress lHost=null;
      try { lHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); }
      catch(Exception e) { System.out.println("Local Host Error");}
      int port = 1234;
      try
      {
         System.out.println("Connecting to " + lHost + " on port " + port);
         Socket client = new Socket(lHost, port);
         System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

         out.writeUTF("Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
         InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
         System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
         client.close();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Connecting to Bridgets_laptop/192.168.56.1 on port 1234
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at GreetClient.main(GreetClient.java:27)
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Connection refused"-part sounds like you either have a firewall which blocks your own application from getting to Socket1234 or you didn't open the ServerSocket 1234 to connect to yet.

Can you connect to the ServerSocket with

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 1234
```

if you use Windows?

Comment: Thanks
I hadn't opened the ServerSocket yet.
I can access it now.